# How to have a select dropdown insert a new row into a specific MySQL Table

Tags: php, mysql, select, dropdown

all.
I'm pretty new to PHP, but I did a lot of research on this specific issue I'm having, and I can't seem to find my issue explained anywhere to my understanding.

Currently, I have a system where a user submits a form with the following attributes:

- Username
- Trainer
- Rank

It then submits the selected answers into a MySQL table called 'pr_members'.
This all works as intended.

However, when I try to add one more field that is a dropdown, where they choose from three options, the code no longer works.
Basically, I have another table (pr_branch), which has the following in it:
[Branch MySQL Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLIXl.png)

The new field I want to add is a dropdown box, which allows for the user filling out the form to select from the 3 Branches in the above table. (Army, Navy, and Air Force).

I currently have the following code for this:

```html
<?php require_once "403check.php";
if ($_SESSION["AddUser"] !== true) {
    UNIVERSAL::buildfooter(1);
    die('<div class="container">Insufficient Permissions</div>');
}?>
<div class="form-group">
    <?php 
    if (isset($_POST["newmember"]) && isset($_SESSION["cur_id"])) {
        PERSONNEL::createnewmember($_POST["username"], $_POST["rank"], $_POST["trainer"], $_POST["branch"]);
    } ?>
    <form name="new-member" method="POST">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input name="username" type="text" class="form-control" for="new-member" required>
        <label for="trainer">Trainer</label>
        <select name="trainer" type="text" class="form-control" for="new-member" required>
            <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Choose An Option</option>
            <?php UNIVERSAL::rendersystemadmin(); ?>
            <?php UNIVERSAL::rendermemberoptions("SELECT * FROM pr_members WHERE Rank_ID >= 4 OR Rank_ID = 0 ORDER BY Rank_ID desc"); ?>
        </select>
        <label for="rank">Rank</label>
        <select name="rank" type="text" class="form-control" for="new-member" required>
            <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Choose An Option</option>
            <?php UNIVERSAL::renderoptions("SELECT * FROM pr_ranks WHERE Rank_ID > 0 and Rank_ID < 3 ORDER BY Rank_ID asc", "Rank"); ?>
        </select>
        <label for="branch">Branch</label>
        <select name="branch" type="text" class="form-control" for="new-member" required>
            <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Choose An Option</option>
            <?php UNIVERSAL::renderoptions("SELECT * FROM pr_branch WHERE branch_ID > 0 ORDER BY branch_ID asc", "branch"); ?>
        </select>
        <br>
        <button class="btn btn-outline-danger" name="newmember" type="submit" for="new-member">Add User</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Now, when I view the page with the form on it, it appears with the dropdown, and the three selections to choose from, but the fields do not have values/text. As such: [Form Dropdown Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8Ild.png)

And finally, the major issue, is that when a user submits the form, it no longer actually inserts it as a new row onto the pr_members table. The page just simply refreshes.

I apologize if there is something obvious missed here. I'm very new to php and tables/MySQL. I just really hope I can learn from this! Thank you!

---

**What I've tried:**

I've tried having simply 'Army', 'Navy', and 'Air Force' values as select options, rather than pulling from the table pr_branch. With this option, the values did appear, but the table still was not created upon submitting the form.

## **EDIT:**

I managed to fix the invisible fields by editing the function renderoptions. But it still does not insert the rows into pr_members after submission of the form.

## **EDIT 2:**

I managed to ensure the tables were being inserted by setting the default value to Null for the Branch column. So yeah, it did have to do with the function.
What do I need to add to this to ensure the branch that is chosen, is inserted into the branch column in pr_members?

```html
        /*
        *   Use the given parameters to create a new member into the database.
        */
        function createnewmember($username, $rid, $trainer) {
            $promoter = htmlentities($trainer);
            $rank = htmlentities($rid);
            $user = htmlentities($username);

            $stmt = $GLOBALS["db"]->prepare("SELECT Member_ID, Member_Username FROM pr_members WHERE Member_Username=?");
            $stmt->execute([$user]);
            $stmt->closeCursor();
            if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
                echo '<div class="container"><div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">An member with the same username already exists.</div></div>';
                return false;
            }

            $stmt = $GLOBALS["db"]->prepare("INSERT INTO pr_members (Rank_ID, Member_Username) VALUES (:rank, :user)");

            $stmt->bindParam(':rank', $rank);
            $stmt->bindParam(':user', $user);
            $stmt->execute();
            $newuser = $GLOBALS["db"]->lastInsertId();
            UNIVERSAL::createnewpromolog($promoter, $newuser, 0, $rank, "New Member");
            UNIVERSAL::createnewadminlog("Added User", $_SESSION["cur_id"], $newuser, "N/A", "User Added");
            header("Location: admin.php?module=newmember");
        }
```

Thanks a bunch for all the help so far!

Comment: The options are blank, so it's probably an issue with `UNIVERSAL::renderoptions`. What does this function do?

Comment: @FelippeDuarte It appears in my global.php as this: '  * Render options within the given query parameter.
  */
  function renderoptions($query, $prefix) {
   $stmt = $GLOBALS["db"]->query($query);
   $stmt->execute();
   foreach ($stmt as $row) {
    echo '<option value='.$row[$prefix."_ID"].'>'.$row[$prefix."_Name"].'</option>';
   }
  }'

So, maybe because the Branch's names do not havethe prefix _Name?

Comment: Seems you already fixed it. So, for the sql issue, update your question with the code that inserts the data into database (function `PERSONNEL::createnewmember`).

Comment: @FelippeDuarte I edited in the code for the function. So, I assume I need to add the branch column/value to be inserted as well. I am not sure how to go about doing so, though.

Comment: Just add another parameter after `$trainer`, like `$branch` and recreate the insert you already did with other tables.

Comment: @FelippeDuarte It seems to have worked! Thank you so much!